# How to make a model point to non-default schema

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model

I've searched all over and I can't find anything related to this.

Basically I have the default schema set to `abc`

In `abc` I have some tables, etc ...............

I want to make a model that uses table `mobile_activity_logs` in schema `def`

The default rails model looks like this:

```
class MobileActivityLogs < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

but the query is on `abc.mobile_activity_logs` and not `def.mobile_activity_logs`

`abc.mobile_activity_logs` doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the database.yml file:

```
tester:
   adapter: mysql2
   database: def
   host: 
   port: 
   username: 
   password: 
   enable_call: true
   flags: CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS
```

In the model:

```
class MobileActivityLogs < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection "tester"
    self.table_name = "mobile_activity_logs"
end
```

This is a bit ugly though as it will make a second connection just to access a different schema :/